# Lower integral of the sum of two functions isn't equal to the lower integral of each summed separately?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I'm trying to figure out the problem above and I know I need to show what I have done so far, but I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Hint: if the actual integral exists, then this cannot possibly work.  So, have you seen any examples of functions where the lower integral exists but the integral does not exist?

Comment: Are we to assume that you are talking about the Riemann integral, with its upper and lower sums?

Comment: No I have yet to see any of these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise. Define $g(x) = 1/2$ if $x$ is irrational and $g(x) = 1$ otherwise. Then the lower integral on $[0,1]$ of $f$ is $0$, and the lower integral of $g$ on $[0,1]$ is $1/2$. However, the lower integral of $f + g$ is $1$.

Edit: Further explanation

Since the rationals and irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that, in any closed interval, $\inf f = 0$, so the lower sum of $f$ is equal to its lower integral which is $0$ on $[0,1]$. Similarly for $g$ the lower integral is simply $1/2$ on $[0,1]$. $f+g$, however, is defined by $(f+g)(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational, and $(f+g)(x) = 3/2$ otherwise. Using the same argument we used to get the lower integrals of $f$ and $g$, we see that $f+g$ has a lower integral of $1$ on $[0,1]$.

For a more details on determining the value of the lower integrals you can read up on the [example of an unintegrable function on wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#An_unintegrable_function)

Comment: Can you possibly explain how you calculated the lower integral and how you came up with the functions?

Comment: I added some explanation. I kind of just pulled the function values out of at random. What was important was that the functions not be integrable, since otherwise the statement would not be true. These ones are also particularly easy to calculate the upper and lower integrals for.

Comment: This is a neat solution. Defining $f(x)$ as distinct constants in two complementary dense subsets makes $\inf$ and $\sup$ in each interval in the Riemann sum to be precisely these constants.